# Get template of a template instance c++11

Tags: templates, c++11

Is there a way to get the template of a template instance?

I have done this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//some template class
template <class T>
struct Hola {
   template<class H> using Base = Hola<H>; //typedef of the self template
   T val;
};

int main() {
  auto h =  Hola<int>{}; //using template with int
  h.val = 6.6;

  auto b = typename decltype(h)::Base<float>{}; //using the same template with float
  b.val = 6.6;

  cout << h.val << endl << b.val << endl;
}
```

and it works as expected.

But I want to know if you can do the same without defining a using clause in the base template. I mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//same class without typedef of self
template <class T>
struct Hola {
   T val;
};

int main() {
  auto h =  Hola<int>{};
  h.val = 6.6;

  using Templ = decltempl(h); //get the template of h
  auto b = Templ<float>{}; //use the template of h with float
  b.val = 6.6;

  cout << h.val << endl << b.val << endl;
}
```

**NOTES**

Assume that there is only one possible source template for the desired type, just to avoid problems with partial specialization.

Comment: Why not `decltype(h.val)`?

Comment: @black `decltype(h.val)` gives you the type of the template argument not the template itself

Comment: @EdwinRodríguez: Templates do not have types. A complete instantiate of a template is a type (or function or variable), but the template *itself* is not a type. `Hola` is not a type; `Hola<int>` is a type.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know. I didn't mention that templates are types. I just want to get the template from a _template_ _instance_, in the same fashion that `decltype` get the type from a _type_ _instance_

Comment: @EdwinRodríguez: `h` is not a "template instance"; it is an expression. `decltype` retrieves the type of that expression. Expressions do not have a "template instance" which can be retrieved. Even if we ignore that, it's not clear how such a thing would even work with partial specialization. If a particular expression's type is a template instantiation, which partial specialization of it does this `decltempl` result in?

Comment: What you are doing already may just be the simplest method to achieve what you want.

Comment: @NicolBolas Which would be the correct terms for what I'm asking?

Comment: maybe it will be possible when introspection comes to C++. Don't hold your breath though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of partial specialization.

```
template<typename T, typename U> struct templ_of;
template<typename T, template<typename> class U, typename A> struct templ_of<T, U<A>> {
    using type = U<T>;
}
template<typename T, typename U>
using rebind = typename templ_of<T, U>::type;
```

This machinery is used for Standard allocators, which are rebound by containers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, decltempl specifier cannot exist in C++.
It's because templates work the way they work ;-)

A class template is like a cake recipe. When comiler notices (in code) that you want to use a specific kind of cake (template instantiation), it bakes one for you (creates a regular class, that doesn't remember being a template) so you can use it as a cake (class), not a recipe (template).

You can mess around with templates at compile-time (read about template metaprogramming), but it's impossible at runtime.

Comment: I want a solution at compile-time. Sorry if I didn't mentioned it, but I thought it was implicit.